# Who has information on this Fondriest Bike we found? Any good?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, frames

Does anyone here know anything about this old Fondriest bike?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "found".  Seems like an older frame (still in good shape though), but a lot of the components look new and of pretty decent quality.  Looks like kind of a frankenbike, where none of the actual components are original.

Comment: In the times of steel frames Columbus was one of leading tube manufacturers, so despite its age the frame is of good quality as well.

Answer (score 1):

Brifters, lugged steel frame, flat pedals, single pivot brakes - I'll go with a late 80s bike or early 90s, but the brifters are probably retrofitted.

The wheels look relatively new.

Looks like a loverly bike and would be a great ride.

I note there is no rust evident anywhere, and its in very tidy overall condition.  So its been well stored and cared for.

The company is Italian, and their current website is http://www.fondriestbici.com/